# Return statement being ignored

Tags: c, windows

## For future readers

Don't code tired. It turns you into a wee bit of a dink.

My problem was that I had two separate outputs that appeared to collide with one another. One was beyond a return statement, so it was alarming that the code was being executed at all. However, it had not occurred to me to use Visual Studio's search function to check every other file to see if there was another reason I was getting output. To my knowledge at that time, there was only a single call to the LoadGLSLFromFile function, when there was actually two.

The results were extreme frustration on my end because I was *positive* that there was no other calls to that function, and that somehow there must be optimizations to my code that's either messing up the ordering of the function, or, the return statement is not functioning as it should (for whatever reason).

If you are going to post a question, I urge you to re-evaluate what is deemed as "relevant" code. You are here because you're not seeing something that others can, after all.

If you read the comments of this, you will see that StoryTeller was trying to get it through to me that what I was assuming was happening was indeed not possible, and that my methods of debugging were incorrect. StoryTeller, if you're reading this, I do sincerely apologize.

===============================

EDIT 2: Note that the issue I am having is that the function is not returning when I told it to. It continues execution beyond the return, inside the same function, until it hits a second one.

So, I am really lost as to why this is occurring, but this is my code. So, usually what I do is I check for critical failures, and if there is a serious issue, I return a known "error" value. However, the return is being ignored in multiple places, and the code is executing in the wrong order. (see the second image for the wrong order)

EDIT:

My problem is that the code is executing beyond the return statements.

```
#include "Loader.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static const GLchar * VSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;\n"
    "out VS_OUT {\n"
    "   vec4 color;"
    "} vs_out;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),\n"
    "                                    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),\n"
    "                                    vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));\n"
    "   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset;\n"
    "   vs_out.color = color;"
    "}\n"
};

static const GLchar* FSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "in VS_OUT {\n"
    "   vec4 color;\n"
    "} fs_in;\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   color = fs_in.color;\n"
    "}\n"
};

static const GLchar* TControlSource[] = {
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "layout (vertices = 3) out;\n"
    "void main(void) {\n"
    "   if(gl_InvocationID == 0) {\n"
    "       gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0;\n"
    "       gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0;\n"
    "       gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0;\n"
    "       gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0;\n"
    "   }\n"
    "   gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;\n"
    "}"

};

GLuint LoadAllShaders() {

    LoadGLSLFromFile("glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);


    GLuint VShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VShader, 1, VSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VShader);
    LogCompileStatus(VShader, "VShader");

    GLuint FShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(FShader, 1, FSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FShader);
    LogCompileStatus(FShader, "FShader");

    GLuint TShader = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(TShader, 1, TControlSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(TShader);
    LogCompileStatus(TShader, "Tessellation Shader");

    GLuint Program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(Program, VShader);
    glAttachShader(Program, FShader);
    glAttachShader(Program, TShader);
    glLinkProgram(Program);
    glDeleteShader(VShader);
    glDeleteShader(FShader);
    glDeleteShader(TShader);
    return Program;
}

void LogCompileStatus(GLuint Shader, char* ShaderName) {
    // Checking compile status of VShader
    if (ShaderName == NULL || sizeof(ShaderName) == 0)
        ShaderName = ("Unnamed Shader with ID: %i" + (char)&Shader);
    GLuint ShaderSuccess = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv(Shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &ShaderSuccess);

    if (ShaderSuccess == GL_TRUE)
        printf("%s successfully compiled\n", ShaderName);
    else {
        GLint LogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(Shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &LogLength);

        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(LogLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(Shader, LogLength, NULL, buffer);

        printf("%s failed to compile.\n%s\n", ShaderName, buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}


GLuint LoadGLSLFromFile(char* location, GLenum ShaderType) {
    if (sizeof(location) < 6 || strstr(location, ".glsl") == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Attempted to load invalid file.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    switch (ShaderType) {
    case(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER):
    case(GL_VERTEX_SHADER):
    case(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER):
    case(GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER):
    case(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER):
    case(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER):
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Shadertype\n");
        break;
    }

    FILE* shaderFile = fopen(location, "r");
    if (shaderFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wurbulgurb\n");
        return 0;
    }
    size_t bufferSize = fseek(shaderFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("File Buffer size: %i\n", (int)bufferSize);


    fclose(shaderFile);
    /*
        glShaderSource(shd, 1, VSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shd);
        LogCompileStatus(shd, "VShader");
    */
    

    return 1;
}
```

The main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <GL\wglew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include "Loader.h"

#define CL_BUFFER (GLfloat[4]) { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f }

int main(void);
void err(int error, const char * msg);
void keypress(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

static GLfloat attrib[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f };

int main(void) {
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;


    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Fididdler", NULL, NULL);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    if (window == NULL)
        return -1;

    LoadGLSLFromFile("./Condoms.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glfwSetErrorCallback(err);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keypress);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        return -1;


    printf("GL Version String: %s \n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    GLuint RProg = LoadAllShaders();
    GLuint VAO;
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    printf("Loading complete");

    


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, CL_BUFFER);
        glUseProgram(RProg);
        glVertexAttrib4fv(0, attrib);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        
        /* End drawing logic*/

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }


    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteProgram(RProg);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
}

void err(int error, const char * msg) {
    printf("Error: %s", msg);
}

void keypress(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    }

    switch (key) {
        case(GLFW_KEY_W): 
            attrib[1] += 0.01f;
            printf("W pressed");
            break;
        case(GLFW_KEY_S):
            attrib[1] -= 0.01f;
            printf("S pressed");
            break;
    }

    switch (key) {
    case(GLFW_KEY_A):
        attrib[0] -= 0.01f;
        printf("A pressed");
        break;
    case(GLFW_KEY_D):
        attrib[0] += 0.01f;
        printf("D pressed");
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the console output for `LoadGLSLFromFile("TessControl.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);`. Note: Line 3 should not happen, as there was a return statement prior to it.
[image: Output 1]

This is the console output for `LoadGLSLFromFile("glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);`
Note: Line 3 should not happen, as there was a return statement prior to it.
[image: Output 2]

There's a return statement specifically blocking further execution, and yet it still executes. I am quite puzzled with this behavior because as far as I am aware, return means "immediately go back to the line that called you".

Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that function. Seeing as the output contains lines that aren't printed by `LoadGLSLFromFile`, you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't the relevant code be what is doing the ignoring, the one producing most of the output shown?

Comment: Are you certain that you aren't simply calling the function several times?

Comment: This is the only instance in which the function is called
https://i.gyazo.com/d891feec073a0619d5fcf4801a23362c.png

Comment: Please edit your post and post the caller code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: ... It's your own calling code that ignores the return value. I'd think it obvious that you need to *check* the return status if you think it matters.

Comment: Lundin: Updated the code


StoryTeller: You're not seeing the issue. The code is continuing to execute after the return statement.

Comment: I'm seeing the issue perfectly, I assure you. The functions returns, and you ignore its return value, thus continuing the execution in `LoadAllShaders` and printing other things. Before you proclaim the language/compiler is broken, try using a debugger.

Comment: The first image shows "Wurbulgurb", a unique string output for only that function. Directly adjacent to that is the return statement. The second image shows "Wurbulgurb", with an "Attempted to load invalid file" later on. If you re-read my code, you will notice that directly adjacent to both outputs is a return 0 statement, and that only one should be executed. Not both.

Comment: On an unrelated note, are you aware that `sizeof(location)` does not give the length of the string that `location` points at? Try `strlen`

Comment: Forgive my frustration here, but I am not having problems with the return *value*. I am having problems with the return *statement*

Comment: The return statement does as advertised. What you have failed to do is to properly debug your code. There is nothing between "Attempted to load invalid file" and "Wurbulgurb" that's supposed to print "GL version string", and yet you are obsessing over a working language construct instead of firing up a debugger and seeing where it is you, the programmer, who made a program logic error.

Comment: That is the problem I am having. The return is NOT doing as it is advertised. A return statement explicitly states to go back to where it was called, but the code is continuing to execute beyond the point of the return statement.

Comment: Fine, blame the floor for a poor dancing performance

Comment: I am not blaming the floor. Given the output, it's either Microsoft's compiler that's messing with the code, OR, the return *statement* is being ignored. Line 1 and 3 in both images proves this.

Comment: Your'e not blaming the floor? "It's either MSVC or the langauge, nothing I did". Printing as a debugging technique is not reliable! Especially if you compare printouts of different streams that are **not** guaranteed to be sequenced (i.e stdout and sdterr).

Comment: I would like to direct you to image 1 and 2, in which both of them have unique outputs on lines 1 and 3, where line 3 should never have been outputted because there's no way it should've reached it. But it does.

Comment: You are calling `LoadGLSLFromFile` twice. It's likely that 2 lines are from different calls.

Comment: Please forgive my frustration here, but I am 100% understanding the implications of what my issue is. There is code being executed that should never have been reached. That output is "Wurbulgurb". Yes, the output is in the wrong order, and it is on different streams. I understand that. But, that output should not be there no matter what, because "Attempted to load invalid file"  has a return statement following it.

Comment: Your first call to `LoadGLSLFromFile` is failing and returning `0` and since you don't check for it's return value, code continues to run and call `LoadAllShaders` which calls again `LoadGLSLFromFile` and that one succeed. Check the return value of your first call to `LoadGLSLFromFile` and then decide if whether or not your code should continue running.

Comment: I am deeply sorry @StoryTeller, Lundin, and ScottHunter. In the main file, I was also calling it. I was wrong. I haven't looked at the main file in long enough that I forgot I had made that function call. I would also like to apologize for getting frustrated. Apparently this was a great indicator that I need to debug my debug practices, and not immediately resort to frustration.

Comment: @StoryTeller If you're still paying attention, please read the intro message.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold - That's mighty big and humble of you. I retract my DV.

Comment: I am very okay with being wrong, and in this instance, I was very wrong. I was actually really hoping I hadn't frustrated you to the point you would not see my public apology, as I strongly feel you deserve one.

Comment: There's actually an interesting phenomenon here that I'd like to call "guts debugging". When posting something mysterious like this on SO and you get a bunch of comments from seasoned programmers, they often have this "guts debugging" ability. That is: they can make a seemingly subjective, yet qualified guess of the actual cause based on trouble-shooting experience. You got several such qualified guesses before even posting the caller code - turns out they were spot on. "Guts debugging" doesn't always work, but it is surprising how often it does.

Comment: Haha, guts debugging needs to not be my first response. I actually bought Pragmatic Programmer by Andrew Hunt, Clean Code by Robert Martin, and Debugging by David Agans, all as a response to it occurring to me that my methods of problem solving need improvement.

Comment: @Lundin Can this post be voted to be preserved as an example? I like how StoryTeller didn't give up on him and how OP honestly apologized afterwards + your comment now makes it even more worthy as an example.

Comment: @KamiKaze All SO posts are preserved unless they are closed.

Comment: @Lundin I was thinking of something like community wiki, to use it as an example for good behaviour. Also with -5 votes I fear it might get closed.

Comment: I'm okay with that personally. If it helps, I'm 100% okay with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the return value is being ignored.  That is exactly what your code is doing:

```
GLuint LoadAllShaders() {

    // return value is ignored
    LoadGLSLFromFile("glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);


    GLuint VShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

Because you don't check the return value, there is nothing to prevent your code from continuing.

Perhaps you're confusing `return` with `exit()`.  The `return` statement returns a value from a function so that the calling function can decide how to proceed.  The `exit` function causes the program to terminate, with the passed in value being the return value of your program.

If you want your program to quit, you should use `exit`.  If not, then you need to check the return value in the above code and act accordingly.

EDIT:

This is why a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) is so important.

After posting your main code, the issue is that you're calling `LoadGLSLFromFile` twice.  You first call it directly from `main`.  Then `main` calls `LoadAllShaders`, which calls `LoadGLSLFromFile` again.

So "Wurbulgurb" prints on the first call, while either "Attempted to load invalid file" or "File Buffer size" is printed on the second call.

Comment: The problem is not that the return value is not being read. The problem is specifically that the "return" statement is being ignored, and it keeps on executing beyond that, inside of the LoadAllShaders() function.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold The `return` statement is not being ignored.  Inside of `LoadGLSLFromFile` you print "Attempted to load invalid file." and then return 0.  At that point control goes back to `LoadAllShaders` which then runs the statements that follow.  It keeps executing because that's exactly what you're telling it to do.

Comment: There is no point at which "File Buffer size" occurs in the program other than in the LoadGLSLFromFile.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold True, but that's not part of the output you posted for the error case.

Comment: Yes it is. It's in the first image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I apologize for speaking to you in a frustrated manner, and hope I did not put a hamper in your day.